# Facebook Graph API vs. user's privacy settings

Tags: php, sdk, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook's Graph API, I'm a little confused about the interaction between the requested application permissions and the user's privacy settings.

I'm developing a web app that allows people to login via Facebook Connect, and then attempts to retrieve their interests and friends list.  I've set the Facebook application permissions as broadly as possible for testing:

> perms="email, user_birthday,
>   status_update, publish_stream,
>   user_hometown, user_location,
>   user_interests, user_relationships,
>   user_work_history"

And yet I'm finding that the only way I can retrieve anything beyond the basic profile information is if the user's privacy settings are set to "Everyone".

Am I missing something?  If the user allows the required permissions during application login, shouldn't that that precedence?

Maybe I'm not using the access_token correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It should, and you are clearly doing something wrong. What are you coding on?

Comment: PHP SDK  If I retrieve the access_token, do I need to feed it back in when requesting the other info?

Comment: You do. I haven't used PHP, I use a rails gem which I believe does exactly that for me. Otherwise, how would Facebook know who is making the request?

Comment: If you make your requests via the facebook->api method then it appends your access token to the query.

Comment: That makes sense.  After login, I retrieve the access token and uid, and then send a request for interests via: "https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/interests?access_token=[access_token]  Is there a step in between that I'm missing?  I should probably look at a couple examples in other SDKs.  The PHP documentation is pretty minimal.

Comment: I think I might have found the issue.  I had looked for the list of permissions that an app can request.  Because music, books, etc. wasn't in the list, I assumed that those fell under "user_interests".  Where is the list of potential permissions?